# I need to find the dates on which I first accessed webpages

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, history, internet-explorer

What is the easiest way to find the first time I visited a given website in:

Firefox 32.0.3
Google Chrome 37.0.2062.124
and IE 11.0.12

I need to know the very first time that I visited each website, I need to do this for several sites so wading through the history by hand is not really practical.

Is there some tool I can use?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a solution to this.  For example, Chrome only keeps 90 days of [history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589).  If you visited a page before that, or cleared your history, you are out of luck.

I dont know about the other browsers, but I would assume they operate in a similar manner.